# Horizontal rules in tabular only one column wide if using xltabular

Tags: tables, xltabular

I am currently working on a document, where I need longtables with the `X`-column type from `tabularx`. After a bit of searching, I found `xltabular`, which works very well for anything that is (or rather was) a longtable. But at the same time it does something weird with my `tabular`- and `tabularx`-based tables, where all horizontal rules only extend to the first column and not all the columns as I would expect them to.

This is an example not using `xltabular`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
    \toprule
    Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 \\ \midrule
    Val 1 & Val 2 & Val 3 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This will produce the following table:

[image: Tabular-based table without using xltabular]

And this is an example using `xltabular`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
    \toprule
    Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 \\ \midrule
    Val 1 & Val 2 & Val 3 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Which in turn will produce the following table:

[image: Tabular-based table while using xltabular]

I looked at the documentation of [`xltabular`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) but could not find anything in there, which would point me in the right direction as to why my tables behave like this.

How can / should I use `xltabular` while preserving the behaviour of my *regular* tables?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I can't reproduce your table. It is as expected, with rules from start to end of table.

Comment: @Zarko That's interessting. Which compiler are you running this on? I originally tried it locally running `latexmk` from a MikTeX-installation, which in turn will run `pdflatex` from pdfTeX. Additionally, I tried the four compilers available on [overleaf.com](http://overleaf.com) (`pdflatex`, `latex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`) to check whether it's just some kind of local issues I'm having, but all compilers yield the same result for me.

Comment: I test with pdLaTeX engine in recent 64-bit MikTeX (updated two days ago). Tray to update your installation (administrator and user mode). It may help.

Comment: @Zarko I updated all my packages, but I still get the same result. I also tried removing all the packages from my disk and reinstall them, just to make sure that everything is really up-to-date, but also still the same (wrong) result. I'll do some more testing later this day to try and narrow this issue down.

Comment: @McDonnough, just tested your MWE and I cannot reproduce the wrong behavior on miktex / win10

Comment: I just ran both examples on my notebook with an updated MikTeX-installation. And contrary to my desktop it works fine there and produces the same result with both pieces of code. Guess I'll check what I have installed on my desktop once more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more un- and reinstalling and updating packages through the MikTeX Console (in both user and admin mode), I finally managed to get everything to work correctly. Based on that and the comments of other people who could not reproduce the problem, my guess is that I had an outdated / bugged version of one of the involved packages installed.

Thus, the solution was to make sure that all packages are really up-to-date.